# Local version of Heroku-Django app does not see vars in .env

Tags: python, django, heroku, environment-variables

I cloned my Heroku-Django project to a new Windows computer. I don't have the local_settings.py file on this computer, so I am trying to set it up to use local environment variables.

I used `heroku config:get SECRET_KEY -s  >> .env` to put the config var into my .env file. That appears to have worked. The .env file now reads `SECRET_KEY='mysecretkey'`. The actual key is correct.

Because I am on Windows, I created a separate Procfile called `Procfile.windows` and it reads: `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

In my production_settings file, I have this line: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`. OS is imported.

When I run `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`, I ultimately get this error:  `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.` However, it does find the .env file: `[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format`.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** This is what my settings module looks like:

__ init.py __:

```
from .base_settings import *
from .production_settings import *

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except:
    pass
```

base_settings.py:

```
import os, dj_database_url

# All the basic Dango/Heroku settings.
# SECRET_KEY is not defined here as I only define it in local_settings.py and production_settings.py.
```

production_settings.py:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', 'localhost']
```

Comment: You shouldn't really combine having a local_settings and using environment variables. The whole point of using env vars in settings is that you don't need to do anything different in the file itself between dev and prod.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Correct. Ultimately my goal is to remove the local_settings entirely. I couldn't get the env vars to work on my other computer so I used the local_settings in the mean time, just to to get the site up. Now that I am on a different computer and I don't have the ignored source code, I figured this is the perfect opportunity to figure out the local env vars. but I still need help as explained in my post.